# loop through subfolders 

Tags: powershell

Hi I would like to create a batch file to get all the sub-folders.Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is trivial in both batch files or PowerShell:

Batch:

```
for /r %%x in (*.sql) do (
    rem "(or whatever)"
    sqlcmd "%%x"
)
```

PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.sql |
    ForEach-Object {
        sqlcmd $_.FullName # or whatever
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Joey , is there any method using sqlcmd to loop through all the subfolders without hardcoding the subfolders path? and for the powershell script last line , could you please provide example for this "sqlcmd $_ # or whatever" ? thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Here is a powershell script I use to get the size of the "School" folder within the Subfolder of each users' home folders. IE. N:\UserName\UserNameOSXProfile\School

SizeOfSchoolFolder.ps1

```
$schoolFolderTotalSize=0

$foundChildren = get-childitem *\*OSXProfile\School
foreach($file in $foundChildren){
    $schoolFolderTotalSize = $schoolFolderTotalSize + [long](ls -r $file.FullName | measure -s Length).Sum
}

switch($schoolFolderTotalSize) {
  {$_ -gt 1GB} {
    '{0:0.0} GiB' -f ($_/1GB)
    break
  }
  {$_ -gt 1MB} {
    '{0:0.0} MiB' -f ($_/1MB)
    break
  }
  {$_ -gt 1KB} {
    '{0:0.0} KiB' -f ($_/1KB)
    break
  }
  default { "$_ bytes" }
}
```

I pulled the adding numbers from:
[Adding up numbers in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630559/adding-up-numbers-in-powershell)

And the making folder size look pretty:
[Get Folder Size from Windows Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813826/windows-command-line-get-folder-size)

And The \*\*OSXProfile\School as a search for a specific sub folder.
[Limit Get-ChildItem recursion depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249085/limit-get-childitem-recursion-depth)

Answer (score -1):

To replace 'xyz' with 'abc' in all the filenames:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.mp3 | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace 'xyz','abc' }
```