# How to list specific files with size via batch file?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, size

We are having problems when a specific files (.ost) are near to 49GB size and I'm trying to find someway to know before it happens.

I'm looking to list remotely a list and also get the size in GB instead of bytes.

The files will be always inside %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook but sometimes cuould be also a renamed folder like %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook_OLD

With command forfiles somehow :'D I get to show the files:

```
>c:\>forfiles /P %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\ /M *.ost /S /C "cmd /c echo @path >@fsize"
```

Suited to me but copied from the post https://superuser.com/questions/64481/is-there-a-windows-command-line-utility-to-list-largest-files-exceeding-specific

But, I'm looking for a clean output as this code works:

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

set "folder=%~1"
  if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"

    for /d %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
        set "size=0"
        for /f "tokens=3,5" %%b in ('dir /-c /a /w /s "%%~fa\*" 2^>nul ^| findstr /b /c:"  "') do if "%%~c"=="" set "size=%%~b"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        call :GetUnit !size! unit
        call :ConvertBytes !size! !unit! newsize
        echo(%%~nxa - !newsize! !unit!
        endlocal
    )

endlocal

exit /b

:ConvertBytes bytes unit ret
setlocal
if "%~2" EQU "KB" set val=/1024
if "%~2" EQU "MB" set val=/1024/1024
if "%~2" EQU "GB" set val=/1024/1024/1024
if "%~2" EQU "TB" set val=/1024/1024/1024/1024
> %temp%\tmp.vbs echo wsh.echo FormatNumber(eval(%~1%val%),1)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ( 
  'cscript //nologo %temp%\tmp.vbs' 
) do endlocal & set %~3=%%a
del %temp%\tmp.vbs
exit /b


:GetUnit bytes return
set byt=00000000000%1X
set TB=000000000001099511627776X
if %1 LEQ 1024 set "unit=Bytes"
if %1 GTR 1024   set "unit=KB"
if %1 GTR 1048576  set "unit=MB"
if %1 GTR 1073741824  set "unit=GB"
if %byt:~-14% GTR %TB:~-14% set "unit=TB"
endlocal & set %~2=%unit%
exit /b
```

From this post:
[How to list all folder with size via batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711180/how-to-list-all-folder-with-size-via-batch-file)

So the idea is to input something like:

```
"ip address" batchfile.cmd
```

And output something like

```
fileName1.ost size 10GB
fileName2.ost size 20GB
fileName3.ost size 20GB
fileName4.ost size 20GB
```

Comment: This is really difficult and ugly in shell script (batch). PowerShell is a much better choice.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Somehow I get it with PS, I can output what I need but I have no clue to how to do it remotely to a target pc.

Comment: That's a different question.