# batch file to compare Folder sizes in bytes

Tags: batch-file, byte, sizeof, directory

Hard drives are big these days and I want to store all my pictures on it and some times check to see if I have added or moved any files out by mistake.

this one is the one that works close to what I need but I don't what it to show me all the folders, just my selected ones

[How to list all folder with size via batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711180/how-to-list-all-folder-with-size-via-batch-file)

I need a simple Batch file that can do a byte count and compare it to a number that it should be echo,  good or not and then same routine on my chosen folder.. 
thanks for the help in advance

```
set "folder=DVD-001 - 4,471,234,796" 

set "size=0

for /f "tokens=3,5" %%b in ('dir /-c /a /w /s "%%~fa\

@echo foldername  !size! Bytes

IF !size! EQU 4471234796 (@echo good) ELSE (@echo oops)

:next folder

set "folder=DVD-002 - 4,590,775,746"

set "size=0

for /f "tokens=3,5" %%b in ('dir /-c /a /w /s "%%~fa\

@echo foldername  !size! Bytes

IF !size! EQU 4590775746 (@echo good) ELSE (@echo oops)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Comparing to the predefined list of folders with sizes:

  ```
  @echo off
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

  for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2*" %%a in ('^
      echo DVD-001: 4471234796: f:\folder1 ^&
      echo DVD-002: 4590775746: d:\another folder ^&
      echo DVD-003: 1111111111: e:\folder 3 ^&
      echo DVD-004: 2222222222: c:\folder 4 ^
  ') do (
      set status=

      rem trim the path
      for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ("%%~c") do set folder=%%~c
      for /l %%c in (1,1,100) do if "!folder:~-1,1!"==" " set folder=!folder:~0,-1!
      for /l %%c in (1,1,100) do if "!folder:~-1,1!"=="\" set folder=!folder:~0,-1!

      rem trim dvd size
      for /f %%b in ("%%~b") do set dvdsize=%%~b

      rem get folder size
      set size=
      if exist "!folder!" (
          rem save penultimate line
          for /f "tokens=2,3*" %%s in ('dir "!folder!" /s /w /a 2^>^&1') do (
              set prev=!cur! & set cur=%%t
          )
          rem combine digit groups
          for /l %%s in (0,1,20) do (
              if "!prev:~%%s,1!" geq "0" if "!prev:~%%s,1!" leq "9" (
                  set size=!size!!prev:~%%s,1!
              )
          )
      ) else (
          set size=NOT FOUND
      )
      if !size!==!dvdsize! (
          echo GOOD %%a: !dvdsize! == !folder!
      ) else (
          if "!size!"=="" set size=ERROR
          echo OOPS %%a: !dvdsize! ^<^> !size! !folder!
      )
  )
  pause
  ```
- A two-way `robocopy` in list-only mode would be more reliable in case both folders exist:

  ```
  @echo off
  set DIR1=d:\somefolder (no trailing slash!)
  set DIR2=e:\anotherfolder (no trailing slash!)
  robocopy /L /njh /njs /ndl /s "%DIR1%" "%DIR2%" | find "%DIR1%"
  if errorlevel 1 (
      robocopy /L /njh /njs /ndl /s "%DIR2%" "%DIR1%" | find "%DIR2%"
      if errorlevel 1 (echo GOOD & goto DONE)
  )
  echo OOPS
  :DONE
  pause
  ```

  It will list the different files as well.

Comment: This program works great for comparing 2 folders but what I have is a folder and a known Byte count that it should be, I don't have 2 folders to compare. I need the program to compare a folder to a  Byte a number.

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm I do have a use for two-way robocopy as well and have already found it usefull.

Comment: OOPS DVD-001 - Mirror <> 4471234796
OOPS DVD-002 - Mirror <> 4590775746
OOPS DVD-003 - Mirror <> 1111111111
OOPS DVD-004 - Mirror <> 2222222222
Press any key to continue . . . this is all I get  one and 2 should be right , also I am not sure how to direct it to the folder such as f:\folder1 or d:\dvd-folder6

Comment: Ah, little by little you expose more details that should have been present in the question :-) I've updated the code.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear on what I meant and sorry I just can't get it to work, maybe it will not work on windows XP or maybe my robocopy Ver. XP010 is the problem.
All I get is ( OOPS DVD-001 - Mirror <> 4471234796 ) even if the FOLDER DVD-001 is the correct size or not. I have tried using other folder names like c:\test as well. I have tried with all in the root of c: and no different. Just to be clear all are folders are on the hard drive none of them are using a CD or a DVD drive.
why does it show me the word Mirror?

Comment: Well, maybe robocopy on XP prints different info, so I've updated the code to look for the word `Bytes` in robocopy statistics which is, alas, locale-specific. However it's still better than `dir /s` that would require several runs to count hidden/system files.

Comment: Try running `robocopy /njh /ndl /nfl /s /is /l /bytes . .` manually and see if it prints the summary with "Bytes : 123456"

Comment: C:\>robocopy c:\DVD-001 /njh /ndl /nfl /s /is /l bytes:123456


------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
     Dirs :       156       156         0         0         0         0
    Files :      9009      9009         0         0         0         0
    Bytes :   4.164 g   4.164 g         0         0         0         0
    Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00

    Ended : Sat Jul 25 08:22:21 2015   ----- yes that folder has 9009 files

Comment: with out putting the 123456 at the end it still runs the same,                 Bytes :   4.164 g   4.164 g

Comment: Why did you put `bytes:123456` to the command line? It's just a sample what to look for in the summary. Please run the command exactly as I typed.

Comment: robocopy /njh /ndl /nfl /s /is /l /bytes . .      ERROR : Invalid Parameter #7 : "/bytes"

Comment: WOW ! it works great and have already found one of my folders had dropped 2 of my files (filenames too long)..
I TB drive tested, 5 more TB to go. 
After it found the problem I ran the (2-way robocopy) found it & fixed it. 
Thank you for your hard work and your patience with me.
THANKS!