# Installed R packages size

Tags: r

Is there a way to know what is the size of each package installed in R?  I mean, the size that each packages have on my computer.

Any comment will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Check out the last answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753172/compute-the-size-of-directory-in-r

Comment: Are you asking about finding that out before it's ever installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or the same without needing `fs` here (in case you are on a proper OS):

```
> system(paste("du -sh", system.file(package="dplyr"), "| awk '{print $1}'"), intern=TRUE)
[1] "2.1M"
>
```

because

```
$ du -sh /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/dplyr
2.1M    /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/dplyr
$
```

Easy to generalize to look over all entries in `.libPaths()[1]`, say.

*Edit:* But as the question was about the whole directory, let's try that too.  Looking at `du --help` makes me learn about `-d 1`  which is what we want there.  Then:

```
 > res <- read.table(pipe("du -d 1 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/"), col.names=c("size", "name"))                                                                                                                  
!> head(res)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    size                                       name                                                                                                                                                                
 1 15376  /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/StanHeaders                                                                                                                                                                
 2   540     /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/restfulr                                                                                                                                                                
 3  1028 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/mlr3learners                                                                                                                                                                
 4  1360       /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ndjson                                                                                                                                                                
 5  3920      /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/viridis                                                                                                                                                                
 6   300  /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/sessioninfo                                                                                                                                                                
 >
```

Obviously this can be dressed up to take the path from `.libPaths()[1]` and to also edit down column names by `gsub()`-ing out the fixed path.  But the gits is there and by not specifying 'human-readable' pretty size we can sort and compute easily too:

```
> head(res[order(-res$size), ])
        size                                              name
1030 2964632                    /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/
137   322800   /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/covid19.model.sa2
187   276324 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/stxBrain.SeuratData
971   153532                  /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH
691    95368               /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rstan
940    85972               /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/GO.db
>
```

*Edit 2*  For kicks, here is a loop over `.libPaths()` aggregating *all* directories as desired.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(.libPaths(), \
       function(d) read.table(pipe(paste("du -d 1", d)),  \
                              col.names=c("size", "name"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

To apply the answer in @GordonShumway, basically you need to find the directory it's installed in and then you can sum the file info. Since all packages have a description file, I use that:

```
system.file("DESCRIPTION", package = "dplyr") |> # replace dplyr with target pkg
  dirname() |>
  fs::dir_info(all = TRUE, recurse = TRUE) |>
  getElement("size") |>
  sum()
```