# Get Total size of data harvested by heat tool

Tags: wix, size, directory-structure, heat, data-harvest

I have used Heat.exe provided by WiX.
It takes a copy of the directory structure which is called harvesting a directory.
What i want is to Get Total size of the data which it harvests.

Is there a solution to it, please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am stuck with this, please help

Comment: You might just want to follow this answer to calculate it yourself - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813826/get-folder-size-from-windows-command-line