# Adding up numbers in PowerShell

Tags: shell, powershell

I am trying to add up two numbers in PowerShell. I have the input the user gives stored in `$Value1` and `$Value2`. However I can't find any way to actually add these numbers up. I tried using the `Measure-Object` cmdlet but I can't seem to get it to work.

How does one add up/substract and multiply numbers in Powershell?

Comment: try `get-help about_operators` and `get-help about_Arithmetic_Operators` .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
PS H:\> $value1 = 10
PS H:\> $value2 = 10
PS H:\> $value1 + $value2
20
```

If your numbers are stored as strings then you'll need to cast them to integers like this:

```
PS H:\> $value1 = "10"
PS H:\> $value2 = "20"
PS H:\> [int]$value1 + [int]$value2
30
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$val1 = 1
$val2 = 2
$result = $val1 + $val2
$result
```

If you are getting input from the user, then you would need to explicitly coerce the numbers to be numbers:

```
[int]$val1 = Read-Host 'Enter value 1'
[int]$val2 = Read-Host 'Enter value 2'
$result = $val1 + $val2
$result
```