# Script to sum the freespace of multiple hard disks on a server

Tags: sum, server, backup, powershell-2.0, hard-drive

I need to sum the free space of 3 hard drive on a server and then do a conditional action. If this value is lower than 2,5TB send an email (alert).

Now I have this script:

---

```
$threshold="2500000000000"
$Totaldisk=Get-WmiObject -class win32_logicaldisk -filter "DeviceID='X:' or DeviceID='Y:' or DeviceID='Z:'" |Measure-Object -Sum freespace|select Sum
if ($Totaldisk -lt $threshold) {Send-MailMessage –From Rajith@chakka.local –To samuele.butt@cerbios.local –Subject “Test Email” –Body “Testing the cmdlet” –SmtpServer srvexc54.cerbios.local}
```

But it doesn't work and gives me the error shown on the print screen, I tried use compare-object but I think is not the right way.

[image]

Important part of an error in plain text:

> Cannot compare "@{Sum=9415107125248}" to "2500000000000" because the objects are not the same type or the object "@{Sum=9415107125248}" does not implement "IComparable".

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! I have fixed the layout of your question for you. The error message will be easier for people to read if you pasted it into the question as text, using the [edit] button. It is easy to copy and paste from the command window using the right mouse click and select *mark* and *copy* from that menu.

Comment: Why are You storing `threshold` integer as a `String`? Note: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13630632/1150918

Have You tried storing it as a plain `int`, like `$threshold=2500000000000` or casting it during comparision, something like this: `if ($Totaldisk -lt [int]$threshold)`.

Comment: Thank you Kamiccolo, I tried with your suggestion, [int] but unfortunately doesn't work and give me this error: Cannot convert value "2500000000000" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."