# How to Recursive Directory Loop, Match a Filename and Manipulate the File

Tags: powershell, recursion

I'm a Powershell novice so apologies for any wrong terminology. I've had a look on SE and I know how to recursively descend into a directory structure, however all the working examples I can find seem to pipe the output of `Get-ChildItem`, which I can't understand how to further work with the file before the loop iterates.

**What I'm trying to do**

- Provide my script with a directory: `C:\Users\Donglecow\myPictures\`.
- Recursively loop through all directories in the defined directory (I have an extensive file structure).
- Find all files which match a filter `thumbnail*.jpg`, EG: `thumbnail_001.jpg`
- Rename the file to `BACKUP-thumbnail*.jpg`
- Check the dimensions of that image in pixels and print them out to the command line

**What I've got so far**

```
param (
    [string]$dir = $pwd
)
write-output "Working from $($dir)"

$foundJpg = get-childitem -Recurse -Filter thumbnail*.jpg $dir
foreach($file in $foundJpg) {
    write-output "Found $($file)"
    #Rename to Backup...
    #Check image dimensions...
    #Do other stuff...
}
```

This works and outputs the correct file name, but when I try to rename the file I get an error.

`Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.replace("thumbnail", "SAFE-thumbnail.jpg") }`

```
Rename-Item : Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no
input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.
At C:\Users\Donglecow\myPictures\med.ps1:9 char:23
+ ... -Item -NewName { $_.Name.replace("thumbnail", "SAFE-thumbnail.jpg") }
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentNoInput,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

I've deducted this is probably because I've tried to adapt from a command that pipes the output as shown in answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791905/loop-through-subfolders) question:

`Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.mp3 | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace 'xyz','abc' }`

Whereas I'm using a different construct for my loop so that I can further interact with each file that I find.

**My environment**

For reference, a snippet of my file structure is below.

```
C:\Users\Donglecow\myPictures\
1\001\thumbnail_001.jpg
1\002\thumbnail_001.jpg
1\003\thumbnail_001.jpg
2\001\thumbnail_001.jpg
etc...
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($file in $foundJpg) {
     $File | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.replace("thumbnail", "SAFE-thumbnail.jpg") }
     #Do other stuff...
}
```

You need to use `$file` as  the input of the command (which you should be able to do via the pipeline as shown above) as this is what your `ForEach` loop is using to represent each item retrieved by `Get-ChildItem` into the `$foundJpg` variable.

Comment: Ah, such a simple solution. Thanks! I hadn't realised that's how the pipeline worked in Poweshell. Coming from Linux I assumed it worked the same on both platforms.